# Como debugar (exibir erros) em um sistema que utiliza o MooTools?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2, mootools

tudo bem?

Não conheço JS a fundo, mas preciso debugar um trecho de código que utiliza o MooTools. QUando informo ao meu código para escrever um array com print_r ou debug (do cakephp), não me é exibido nada e no console fica assim:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
(<pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclic
```

O cakephp tenta exibir o erro, mas o ajax/js/mootools (não sei qual) esconde o erro, não deixando aparecer.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Grato! =)

Comment: `+1` por usares MooTools :) Podes colocar o código MooTools que tens? imagino que tenhas uma classe Request(?).

Comment: Na verdade, Sérgio, o código está todo em PHP. Porém, como o sistema utiliza o MooTools, parece que ele bloqueia a exibição de erro através de ajax de alguma forma.

Esse código é o que aparece no console.

Comment: Mas qual é o código MooTools que faz um pedido ajax? Deves ter um Request (a Classe de ajax). Sem isso não dá para saber sequer que pedido ajax estás a enviar e que tipo de dados está a ser esperado...

Comment: Será este?
`$(document).find('body').append(frame);
var f = $(new Element('form'));
f.attr('action',webroot('Imagens/upload_avulsa'));
f.attr('target','upload_frame');
f.attr('method','post');
f.attr('enctype','multipart/form-data');
f.append($(this));
  
$(document).find('body').append(f);
f.submit();`

Comment: Não é esse trecho. E estou a ver nesse trech MooTools misturado com jQuery, isso não é bom. Se colocares o código todo na pergunta ou num jsFiddle posso ajudar mais.

Comment: Este é o código da página completo:
https://jsfiddle.net/tohko3vn/1/

Comment: Esse código é basicamente jQuery, não tem quase nada de MooTools. Esse site está online? para ver a resposta na consola?

Comment: Conseguiste resolver o problema?